# why does PHP unit not work unless i provide it a file?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am wondering what I have to do inside my tests directory to stop from going phpunit SetUp.php and just do phpunit and have it run all the tests in that directory?

My directory is:

- tests

  - SetUp.php

The class is:

```
class SetUp extends  PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $_wp_query;

    public function setUp(){        
        parent::setUp();

        global $wp_query;

        if($this->_wp_query == null){
            $this->_wp_query = $wp_query;
        }
    }

    public function testIsArray(){
        $this->assertTrue(is_array($this->_wp_query));
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your file to SetUpTest.php and the class to SetUpTest

PHPUnit only auto picks up classes ending in the word Test

Comment: +1 - That can be changed via a directory entry in a phpunit.xml configuration file, but it is the default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Provide the directory to phpunit, i. E. `phpunit .tests/` or just `phpunit .` if your current working directory is test/

Answer (score 0):

I also use the default XML file name, and set all your parameters in there.  I do not use SetupTest.php as a name, but rather we use SetUp.php.test so we can strip these easily for release.

The default phpunit.xml.dist will be processed, and this may contain all your configuration settings, as well as directory, file, output settings.